# Action Listener "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I just started learning Swing basics and tried reproducing a textbook example but I am getting an error when I try to compile.

There are three classes.

FirstWindow class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class FirstWindow extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;

    public FirstWindow() {

    super();
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    setTitle("First Window Class");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton endButton = new JButton("Click to end program.");
    endButton.addActionListener(new EndingListener());
    add(endButton);
    }
}
```

EndingListener class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class EndingListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

DemoWindow class (the one with the main method):

```
public class DemoWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    FirstWindow w = new FirstWindow();
    w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile DemoWindow, I get:

```
DemoWindow.java:5: error cannot find symbol
        FirstWindow w = new FirstWindow();
        ^
  symbol:   class FirstWindow
  location: class DemoWindow
DemoWindow.java:5: error cannot find symbol
        FirstWindow w = new FirstWindow();
                            ^
  symbol:   class FirstWindow
  location: class DemoWindow
2 errors
```

When I try to compile FirstWindow specifically, I get:

```
FirstWindow.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        endButton.addActionListener(new EndingListener());
                                        ^
  symbol:   class EndingListener
  location: class FirstWindow
1 error
```

When looking around for a solution, the only issue I saw answered was something along the lines of an improper import statement (import java.awt.* or the likes).

Can someone help me figure out what exactly went wrong?

---

The compiling issue has been solved. I had to compile all classes in bulk.

My new issue is that after compiling, I get an error when I try to run DemoWindow.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class DemoWindow
```

All files are in one directory.

Comment: how are you compiling `DemoWindow` ?

Comment: what is your packages structure?

Comment: Using a CLI. So something like "javac DemoWindow.java" while in the proper directory.

Comment: Use javac *.java to compile all at the same time.

Comment: First compile EndingListener, then FirstWindow and then DemoWindow or compile them at once using javac source1 source2 ...

Comment: All in one directory, so only using 1 default package.

Comment: So I just tried compiling using *.java and that worked.

Comment: Earlier, however, when I tried compiling EndingListener first and so on, it didn't work. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Ah, not when I try to run DemoWindow after compiling, I get:

Comment: Each file is dependent on another. If one isnt compiled yet, the other will fail. So bulk compile is necessary

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class DemoWindow

Comment: All files are in one directory.

Comment: Put all classes in one file name it with class which has main inyour case DemoWindow , Remove public from othe classes except DemoWindow and compile.

Comment: Compile Like this May be you kno this; **pathtodir>javac DemoWindow.java**

Comment: The compiling worked. Now the problem is I can't run the program.

Comment: Can you show me how are you running program?

Comment: From the cli, in the directory where all the files are, I use the command "java DemoWindow".

Comment: Have you set path upto jdk/bin for java?

Comment: Yes. My PATH environment variable goes to the bin directory in jdk.

Comment: Close cmd and Open it but run it as an administrator.Check class files are made of these classes or not.

Comment: Still having the same problem. Each class file is there, or so it seems. Getting the same error when I run cmd as admin.

Comment: Please provide the exact command that you are using to run your code.  This will make it easier to identify your problem.

Comment: Instead of asking one question, then throwing an *edit* comment at the bottom to ask a new one, actually *ask a new question*. Or, since this one has no answers yet, [edit] your question to highlight *what you actually want to know*. Rewrite the whole thing, if necessary, to shift the focus to *the actual problem you're having*. At the moment, the whole focus of the question is on *a problem you used to have*, with a single line at the bottom about the problem you *actually have now*. Highlight the *actual thing you want an answer to*.